# How to use the result of mysql_fetch_array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, fetch

I'm using a while statement on this and I can echo each row fine i.e

```
echo $row['myrow'];
```

but what I want is to have the result put into a link like so:

```
echo "<img src='http://www.mysite.com/images/$row['myrow'].jpg'>";
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either echo it this way:

```
echo "<img src='http://www.mysite.com/images/{$row['myrow']}.jpg'>";
```

Or, IMHO much better, this way:

```
echo "<img src='http://www.mysite.com/images/".$row['myrow'].".jpg'>";
```

Give the [documentation on double quoted-strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) a quick refresh.

Comment: @Baszz: Whether the element needs to be closed or not depends on the [doctype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration) in use.

Answer (score 2):

Another nice way to do it is to only use PHP for the dynamic part of the code. I think it results in nicer looking code.

```
<img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/<?php echo $row['myrow']; ?>.jpg">
```

Then of course the whole img tag should not be in a PHP code block, since it regular HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of your quotes...
Try this:

```
echo '<img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/'.$row['myrow'].'.jpg" />';
```

Also notice that you didn't close the element.

Comment: sorry hit enter - if i wanted: echo $ $row['price'];

Comment: It's basic but it's like this: echo '<img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/'.$row['price'].'.jpg" />';

Answer (score 0):

Accessing array elements and object properties/methods inside the string must be enclosed in curly braces ([string parsing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing))

```
echo "<img src='http://www.mysite.com/images/{$row['myrow']}.jpg'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

to make it complete, lol

```
echo "<img src='http://www.mysite.com/images/$row[myrow].jpg'>";
```

Comment: Note that you shouldn't be using just `$foo[bar]` if it's outside of quotes.

Answer (score 0):

you have write your **site url** on place of **example.com**

```
echo "<img src='example.com/images/'.$row['myrow'].'.jpg'>";
```