# while mysql_fetch_array adding letters before or after the result?

Tags: php, string, concatenation

I'd like to display a price in different currencies, starting with only the numerical value and then appending the currency. I tried this way:

```
echo $ $row['price']
// or
echo £ $row['price']
```

but I receive an error, why?

Comment: use quotes around dollar/pound symbols and concatenate the price to the first string using .

Comment: Firstly, please post a better explanation of what you are trying to do, along with more code examples and the error message itself.

Secondly, the above could should be creating a parse error.  The first (`$ $row['price']`) is a variable variable, which I am guessing is not what you are expecting - while the second ('£ $row['price']) is not even valid PHP code!

Comment: thay are **apparently** taking the same classes, [mysql_fetch_array - how to use $result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307770/mysql-fetch-array-how-to-use-result)

Answer (score 4):

First, what I suggest is reading the error and trying to understand what it's trying to tell you. Often, errors don't just break everything, but most importantly try to give you clues as to why you might be wrong! Your code is speaking to you, listen to it!

Second, and I think more importantly, try reading introduction documentation before asking a question here. While we love helping out newbies, we can't read the documentation for them, else we would be doing it all day.

The [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php) is extremely well made, so you should begin there. For example, you might want to read on [variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php) and [basic syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php). You would have learned that [every instruction in PHP needs a semi-colon at the end](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php), and that [everything you want to be printed out on the screen needs to be marked as a string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).

Let's take a look at your code:

```
echo $ $row['price']
```

Returns the error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ',' or ';' in [...]`

It says "`expecting ;`". It should give you a clue to put a semi-colon at the end of your line.

Now you know about strings and semi-colons, you should be writing:

```
echo '$' $row['price']
```

But oh, another error!

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' in
```

"Unexpected variable". Hmm, looks like PHP didn't like getting a second variable didn't it? Let's take a look at the documentation. Every time you want to know more about something in PHP, just go to `php.net/[word]`. Let's try with `php.net/echo`. Turns out, you have to either pass your string to echo as one or two arguments. Either separate them with a comma to make them two arguments, or [merge them in one string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)! Your choice!

And tada,

```
echo '$'.$row['price'];
```

it should work!

Answer (score 3):

Very easy:

```
echo '$' . $row['price'];
echo '£' . $row['price'];
```

Answer (score 2):

[Read this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) so you know exactly what can (and can't) be done with PHP strings.

You need to do this:

```
echo '$ '.$row['price'];
```

...or this...

```
echo "£ {$row['price']}";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty basic [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)...

```
echo "$ " . $row['price'];
```

Comment: Ok :) guess because there's no alphanumeric characters attached to it.

Comment: @Rijk you are absolutey right about this, except it will work when it does not make a valid variable name, e.g. `echo "$1"` works, but `echo "$one"` looks for a variable and triggers an error if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Actually, playing around with it, it's quite interesting what you can and can't do with this. Consider this: `$one = 'two'; $two = 2; echo "${$one}";` prints '2' but this `echo "$ {$one}";` prints '$ two'

Answer (score 0):

This any good?

```
echo "${$row['price']}"
or
echo "£{$row['price']}";
```

Comment: The first line possibly won't work, for reasons discussed below CodeCaster's answer. You would need to escape the first dollar sign, like `\$`.